Configuring lsp-java jdt.ls to write its files outside the project
Is there any configuration in lsp-java to setup jdt.ls to not create .project, .settings, bin etc files at the root of the repo being built? I'd like to have those setup instead in the workspace directory I've configured under emacs via lsp-java-workspace-dir
